# Change Label text with ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

I got very basic question. Why this is not working?!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               width="1000" height="550" minWidth="960" backgroundColor="#F2F0F0">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:Label id="test1" x="43" y="259" text="Label"/>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            test1.text = "Yay! This works...!";
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:Application>
```

I got this error: **Access of undefined property.**

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're setting the text before the component is created.  Try putting the assignment into a method and calling the method on creationComplete:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
           width="1000" height="550" minWidth="960" backgroundColor="#F2F0F0" 
           creationComplete="onCreationComplete()">
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<s:Label id="test1" x="43" y="259" text="Label"/>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        public function onCreationComplete():void {
            test1.text = "Yay! This works...!";
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
</s:Application>
```